# Class Library Reference after imports, Can't See Value(Mouse Over)/AddWatch of Variable ONLY during Debugging

Tags: vb.net, class, debugging, dll

I am relatively new to VB.Net and I am still in the process of learning the language. So basically i have a Class Library with a public structure as shown below.

Class Library test_class

[image: Img1]

```
    Public Structure Setting_User_List
        Public Const TableSettingUserList As String = "Setting_User_List"
        Public Const SUserListID As String = "UserListID"
        Public Const SUserListUserNo As String = "UserNo"
        Public Const SUserListUserName As String = "UserName"
        Public Const SUserListUserAction As String = "UserAction"
        Public Const SUserListUserExpires As String = "UserExpires"
    End Structure
```

After i have compiled it and built it, i wish to add the test_class.dll as a reference to a separate project, calling the const as declared in the previous image.

Everything works perfectly fine, i could imports the namespace and all the public const are available to me, and it is also usable as shown in the following image:

**During Designer Time**

[image: img2]

```
    Imports test_class.Setting_User_List_test

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub testsub()
            Dim a As String = SUserListID
            Beep()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            testsub()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

But the main problem comes when i am debugging the program. Although the program would still run and the public const string are still recognizable for the duration of the run-time. i noticed an error when i try to add watch to the variable or simply mouse-hovering over the const as shown here

**During Debugging Time** it gives the message as shown

[image: Img3]

"'SUserListID' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

But funny thing is the variable "a" i declared could read get the const information from "SUserListID" and shows a value in Watch.

I apologies if my question isn't too clear, but i do sincerely hope somebody out there could shed light to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post code and format it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, your suggestion has been noted.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you declare the constants in a class or module? Personally, I would never use a structure for the declaration of constants alone. Any type should be a class by default and you should only consider a structure if you have specific need of a structure. If you have no instance fields then you don't need a structure so don't use one.

Comment: Something cannot be both a constant and a variable. The whole point of a constant is that it doesn't vary, thus it is not a variable. Your constants are just constants.

Comment: You really ought to get your naming convention sorted out.  You're using underscores in some places and not others, upper-case letters in some places and not others.  You're all over the place.  You should really not be using underscores at all. and you should be starting identifiers with an upper-case letter except for variables/parameters and also starting words within identifiers with upper-case letters, e.g. `SomeType`, `SomeMember`, `someVariable`.

Comment: thank you for your response. i have declared it as a class and still have the same problem. Also, i am well aware that i have declared it as a constant and i do not want it to change. i have used underscore with my naming convention because it is the name of the table in my organization's database. it improves readability for all my other colleague.

Comment: "i am well aware that i have declared it as a constant and i do not want it to change". I'm not talking about how you declared it.  I'm talking about the fact that you said things like "calling the **const variables** as declared".  They are not variables. They are constants.  The whole point of a constant is that its value constant, i.e. **NOT** variable. Thus calling them variables is completely inaccurate.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ahhh kids....

Comment: Ok, i understand i use them interchangeably and yes they do not have the same meaning.  Apologies for the confusion. But this is now starting to divert from main question. So is there any way to solve this?